# Nested Resources w/ Rails 5.1 form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Per [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197) I can see that an array should be passed to `form_with`'s model param. However, when I supply the following:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@trip, @activity], local: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Rails will return - `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method activity_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f80231e3070>:0x007f8023010dd8>):`

My routes file looks like:

```
  resources :trips do
    resources :activities
  end
```

The output of `rake routes` looks like -

```
     trip_activities GET    /trips/:trip_id/activities(.:format)          activities#index
                     POST   /trips/:trip_id/activities(.:format)          activities#create
   new_trip_activity GET    /trips/:trip_id/activities/new(.:format)      activities#new
  edit_trip_activity GET    /trips/:trip_id/activities/:id/edit(.:format) activities#edit
       trip_activity GET    /trips/:trip_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#show
                     PATCH  /trips/:trip_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#update
                     PUT    /trips/:trip_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#update
                     DELETE /trips/:trip_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#destroy
               trips GET    /trips(.:format)                              trips#index
                     POST   /trips(.:format)                              trips#create
            new_trip GET    /trips/new(.:format)                          trips#new
           edit_trip GET    /trips/:id/edit(.:format)                     trips#edit
                trip GET    /trips/:id(.:format)                          trips#show
                     PATCH  /trips/:id(.:format)                          trips#update
                     PUT    /trips/:id(.:format)                          trips#update
                     DELETE /trips/:id(.:format)                          trips#destroy
```

And my activities_controller.rb -

```
  before_action :set_activity, only: %i[show update edit destroy]

  def edit; end

  def update
    dates = calculate_datetimes(params[:date_range])
    @activity.assign_attributes(name: params[:name],
                                summary: params[:summary],
                                start_datetime: dates[0],
                                end_datetime: dates[1])
    if @activity.save
      flash[:success] = 'Activity successfully updated'
      redirect_to(@trip)
    else
      set_humanized_daterange
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_activity
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**tl;dr** - how should I setup my form_with for a nested resource, and why is this form thinking I want to use the `activity_path`? Ideally I'd like to move this form into a partial and use the same form for both my #new and #edit actions.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try specifying the model and url separately:

```
form_with(model: @activity, url: [@trip, @activity])
```

According the docs the the values for `url` are "Akin to values passed to url_for or link_to" so using an array should work.

This also works with shallow nesting since the array is compacted.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to add the url to the route you want the form to point to, ie: `, url: trip_activity_path` or whatever the path you are hitting is

Answer (score 8):

Adding to [max answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919792/2565946), if you want to support shallow nesting you can also use:

`form_with(model: [@trip, @activity])`

And change the render on your edit.html.erb to pass nil to trip, like:

`<%= render 'form', trip: nil, activity: @activity %>`

and keep it passing the trip model in your new.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

Changing the url is fine, but you can instead change the model which allows the builder to infer the url and any scoping etc:

```
<%= form_with(model: child.new_record? ? [@parent, child] : child, local: true) do |form| %>
```

new/edit views: `<%= render 'form', child: @child %>`

controllers will need to set @parent from url params, which is convention for nested resources anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not an answer, just a small debugging tip

For me specifying the model like so works great

```
<%= form_with(model: [@trip, @activity]) do |form| %>
  # form contents
<% end %>
```

but I was getting weird errors.

Make absolutely sure `@trip` and `@activity` are both instances of those models (in my case, one was simply an id e.g. `"22"`, since I had incorrectly defined the `set_trip` method in the trips controller. And so I was getting weird errors. Once I made sure `@trip` and `@activity` were both properly defined instance variables, it worked as expected.