# how to modify form_with when using nested resources in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, nested-resources

I am learning to use nested resources in rails. To keep it simple and reproducible I have setup a very simple blog app with two resources `posts` and `comments`. Most of the code has been generated by scaffold.

I have successfully modified `post#show` to display `comments` below each post, the link to `Add New Comment` also renders the `new comment` form. However I can not save the comments and get a routing error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/posts/1/comments/new"

A comparison of the comment partial form

**original/before nesting resources:**

```
<%= form_with(model: comment, local: true) do |form| %>
```

**modified/after nesting resources:**

```
<%= form_with(url: new_post_comment_path, 
    scope: :comment, local: true) do |form| %>
```

I have pushed the code to [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/blog/tree/master), with separate branches `master` without nested resources and `nestedRoutes` with nested resources. Will appreciate help of the community.

Note: Answers to [Nested Resources w/ Rails 5.1 form_with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919115/nested-resources-w-rails-5-1-form-with) did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the url you are passing is the `new_post_comment_path`, when you probaby want your form to go the create path. Based on your routes I assume this looks like `post_comments_path`.

That’s why you get the error you see, there is no POST method defined for the `new` path (only GET).