# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

i have created project scaffold and stage scaffold.i have a rendered a button on show page of the project to that open a form of stages. but i am getting no method error. i want to pass project_id to stage created. i have one to many association between project and stage.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRfxQ.png)

projects_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end

  def show
    @project=Project.find(params[:id])
    @stages = Stage.all
  end
```

stages_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @stages = Stage.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @stages = Stage.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end


  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @stage = @project.stages.build(stages_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stage.save
        format.html { redirect_to @stage, notice: 'Stage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stage }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages
  end
```

model project.rb

```
has_many :stages
```

rake routes

```
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                    tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                                                                         tasks#index
                          POST   /tasks(.:format)                                                                         tasks#create
                 new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)                                                                     tasks#new
                edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                tasks#edit
                     task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)                                                                     tasks#show
                          PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)                                                                     tasks#update
                          PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)                                                                     tasks#update
                          DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)                                                                     tasks#destroy
           project_stages GET    /projects/:project_id/stages(.:format)                                                   stages#index
                          POST   /projects/:project_id/stages(.:format)                                                   stages#create
        new_project_stage GET    /projects/:project_id/stages/new(.:format)                                               stages#new
       edit_project_stage GET    /projects/:project_id/stages/:id/edit(.:format)                                          stages#edit
            project_stage GET    /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#show
                          PATCH  /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#update
                          PUT    /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#update
                          DELETE /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#destroy
                 projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                                                      projects#index
                          POST   /projects(.:format)                                                                      projects#create
              new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                                                                  projects#new
             edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             projects#edit
                  project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#show
                          PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#update
                          PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#update
                          DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#destroy
```

project show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Add Stage", new_project_stage_url(@project), :class=>"button primary small" %>
```

[updated error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRfxQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using nested routes but in `form_with` you have not specified that. Try to change the `form_with` like this:

```
form_with(model: stage, url: [@project, stage])
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919792/4207394

You will have to check the variable names, i.e., the `stage` variable should have the new `Stage` object and `@project` variable should have the `Project` object or else please change the names accordingly.

Comment: hey now i can render the form but on submit i am not able to save data into table of stage into database.

Comment: You can check the logs (terminal where you have ran the command `rails s`) to see what error you are getting while submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an arror because in your new method you are setting a variable called @stages

```
def new
  @stages = Stage.new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

but in your view you are using a variable called @stage.

Just change @stages into @stage in your controller method #new and you might be good to go like so :

```
def new
  @stage = Stage.new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

And in you view :

```
<% if @stage.errors.any? %>
```

Comment: def new @stage = Stage.new @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) end generates error- undefined method `stages_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f39800d6e78>:0x00007f39800dbb30>

Comment: edit: when you type `rails routes` in your console do you see a stages_path route ? I think you are trying to use a route that doesn't exist in your app

Comment: i have added the routes in question