# How do you toggle the state from a user with buttons on a page from another table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, datatable, routes, controller

I have a rails application with `Events` and `Users` and compared them in a third table `UserEventStates`, which belongs to Users and Events and has an integer named state and makes it possible to set the state for an user for any event separately/different. **Now I would like to update the state for the user for this event when the matching button was clicked, how can I do this with Turbo?**

```rb
# models/event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_event_states
  has_many :users, through: :user_event_states
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_event_states
end

# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_event_states
  has_many :events, through: :user_event_states
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_event_states
end

# models/user_event_state.rb
class UserEventState < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated answer:

If I got the relationships right:

```rb
# models/event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_event_states
  has_many :users, through: :user_event_states
end

# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_event_states
  has_many :events, through: :user_event_states
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_event_states
end

# models/user_event_state.rb
class UserEventState < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_event_states
end
```

And I understand your goal:

> I would like to have buttons for each user and update only the state from the selected user

Then here are some things I would change:

Create a `UserEventStatesController`:

```rb
# app/controllers/user_event_states_controller.rb
class UserEventStatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event
  before_action :set_user_event_state, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  ...

  def update
    if @user_event_state.update(user_event_state_params)
      # action to perform on success
    else
      # action to perform on fail
    end
  end

  ...
  
  private

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end

  def set_user_event_state
    @user_event_state = @event.user_event_states.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_user
    @user = @user_event_state.user
  end

  def user_event_state_params
    params.require(:user_event_state).permit(:event_id, :user_id, :state)
  end
end
```

And change your `EventsController` back to a more standard controller:

```rb
#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
before_action :set_event, only: %i[ show edit update destroy]

def show
  # get *ALL* UserEventStates for this Event
  @ues_events = UserEventState.where(event_id: @event.id)
end

private

def set_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:description, :date, :meeting_time, :start_time, :end_time)
end
```

Nest `UserEventState` routes under `Event`:

```rb
# config/routes

devise_for :users

resources :events do
  resources :user_event_states
end
```

Run `rails routes` from your terminal to check the prefixes of the routes. Should look like this:

```
$ rails routes
                     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
...
    event_user_event_states GET    /events/:event_id/user_event_states      user_events_states#index
                            POST   /events/:event_id/user_event_states      user_events_states#create
 new_event_user_event_state GET    /events/:event_id/user_event_states/new  user_events_states#new
edit_event_user_event_state GET    /events/:event_id/user_event_states/edit user_events_states#edit
     event_user_event_state GET    /events/:event_id/user_event_states/show user_events_states#show
                            PATCH  /events/:event_id/user_event_states/:id  user_events_states#update
                            PUT    /events/:event_id/user_event_states/:id  user_events_states#update
                            DELETE /events/:event_id/user_event_states/:id  user_events_states#destroy
```

Now to views:

```
#app/views/events/show.html.erb

<% @ues_events.each do |ues_ev| %>
  <%= ues_ev.user.email %>
  <%= ues_ev.state %>
  <%= ues_ev.night %>
  <% form_with model: ues_ev, url: [@event, ues_ev] do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :state %> <!-- or whatever kind of input :state needs to be -->
    <%= form.submit 'Zusagen' %>
  <% end %>
```

The form should submit a PATCH request to `/events/:event_id/user_event_states/:id`, which will hit the `UserEventStatesController#update` action.

The `params[:user_event_state]` should be `{ state: 'form response' }`

**upgrade idea:**

Submitting a form and getting redirected can be slow and not very smooth in terms of user experience.

Say you want to say right on the `events#index` page and just click buttons to toggle the state for a few users.

You could look at replacing your forms with buttons or links that use:

- Rails 6 and prior: unobtrusive javascript & AJAX to submit data remotely. [Here's a tutorial I recommend](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/)
- Rails 7: use [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/)

---

#### First answer:

`get 'right route'` can be whatever you want, as long as it is a viable URI path.

Any symbols in the path are accessible via `params`

So `get 'events/:events_id/users/:id/update-event-state' to: ...`

Would have `params[:event_id]` and `params[:id]`.

Since it looks like you need only `:event_id` params, it doesn't have to include user.

`get 'events/:event_id/user-state', to: ...`

But it also doesn't have to follow convention:

`get 'foo/bar/baz/:event_id', to: ...`

If you want to nest the route, you can, but you lose control over what the URL will be:

```rb
resources :events do
  # url would be events/:id/update_user_event_state
  get :update_user_event_state, on: :member
  
  resources :users do
    # url would be events/:event_id/users/update_user_event_state
    get :update_user_event_state, on: :collection

    # url would be events/:event_id/users/:user_id/update_user_event_state
    get :update_user_event_state, on: :member
  end
end
```

Also, I think you have a typo. It should be like this, I think:

```rb
def update_user_event_state
   @ues_event.update(state: 1)
   # not self.update
end
```

Comment: Please post your three models with relationships. I think I understand what you need.

Comment: For the form error, see my corrected form in the answer.

Comment: [this is the solution to nested resources using form_with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919792/1880203)

Comment: For using Turbo, specifically, Turbo Drive, see [this tutorial](https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/turbo-drive)

Comment: So, I don’t have to do anything for using Turbo with forms, right?